# finding duplicate source code

Tags: plsql, automation, duplicates, static-code-analysis

I'm analyzing some legacy code. It is about 80.000 lines of old plsql code. On a fist look there is quite some duplication in the source which needs to be removed. Instead off doing diff's manual and looking at each file there must be some tool/commandline confu out there to detect duplicate lines of source code.

My goal is to make an educated guess about the minimal size of a rewrite of source and about how much actual knowledge is captured in this program. I wrote some a basic static code analyzer to find the amount of control statements IF ELSE FOR etc and Functions in each file.
But duplicated code still needs to be removed from my statistics.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546487/tools-to-identify-code-duplications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [Simian - Similarity Analyser](https://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/)? (Just checked and it's no longer free, but it is available for a period of 15 days for evaluation purposes.)

> Simian (Similarity Analyser)
> identifies duplication in Java, C#, C,
> C++, COBOL, Ruby, JSP, ASP, HTML, XML,
> Visual Basic, Groovy source code and
> even plain text files. In fact, simian
> can be used on any human readable
> files such as ini files, deployment
> descriptors, you name it.

I have used it in practice and it does work well.

Comment: It was the best and easy to use tool I came across. The option to change the block size was very nice. -threshold=8

Answer (score 0):

[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) has duplication detection and claims to support PL/SQL, though I've never used it for that.

Comment: Seems to be a commercial plugin for sonar. It is priced with about 3200 EUR. http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/plsql/

Comment: The other issue with sq is that to narrow the focus is pretty time-consuming as you need to define lots of setting files. It is not like drag and drop some files and then quickly analyze.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to beg/borrow/steal/write a plsql parser and compare the resulting abstract syntax trees. With the size of the code base you have, that might be worthwhile. There would be other uses for the parser once you're done.

Comment: I found an antlr plsql grammar which after some minor fixes worked. I got a AST tree's from the source now. but I'm still clueless about how to get metrics out of them using this antlr tool.

Comment: My theory is that duplicate code should parse to nearly identical AST's. As for metrics, you can count nodes of a specified type (e.g. statements, procedure definitions).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sddforeclipse/

It is opensource, and is said to be used by commercial software.   It is a plugin to Eclipse, by the way.